# GCC: why global variable missing in dynamic symbol table?

Tags: gcc, symbols

Code:

```
//test.c
#include <stdio.h>
int v_flag = 0xCACA;

void main(int argc, char* argv[]){
  printf("v_flag = %d, &v_flag=%p \n", v_flag, &v_flag);
  v_flag++;
  printf("v_flag = %d\n", v_flag);

}
```

Compile:

```
$ gcc -fPIC -o test test.c
```

Run: (not important)

```
$ ./test

v_flag = 51914, &v_flag=0x601034
v_flag = 51915
```

Read symbol tables:

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-8)
...

$ ld --version
GNU ld version 2.23.52.0.1-16.el7 20130226
...

$ readelf -s test

Symbol table '.dynsym' contains 4 entries:
   Num:    Value          Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
     0: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT  UND
     1: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND printf@GLIBC_2.2.5 (2)
     2: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND __libc_start_main@GLIBC_2.2.5 (2)
     3: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  WEAK   DEFAULT  UND __gmon_start__

Symbol table '.symtab' contains 65 entries:
   Num:    Value          Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
                            ...
    58: 0000000000601048     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT   25 _end
    59: 0000000000400450     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   13 _start
    60: 0000000000601038     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT   25 __bss_start
    61: 0000000000400514    89 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   13 main
    62: 0000000000601034     4 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT   24 v_flag
                            ...
```

**Question 1**: Why the global variable *v_flag* appears in *symtab*, but not in *dynsym*? (note: disable optimizations "-O0" does not help)

Following up Question 1, adding "*-rdynamic*" flag will make *v_flag* (and also others) appear in *dynsym*:

```
$ gcc -rdynamic -o test test.c

$ readelf -s test

Symbol table '.dynsym' contains 18 entries:
   Num:    Value          Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
     0: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT  UND
     1: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND printf@GLIBC_2.2.5 (2)
     2: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND __libc_start_main@GLIBC_2.2.5 (2)
     3: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  WEAK   DEFAULT  UND __gmon_start__
                            ...
    11: 0000000000400670     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   13 _start
    12: 0000000000601038     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT   25 __bss_start
    13: 0000000000400734    89 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   13 main
    14: 0000000000400600     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   11 _init
    15: 0000000000400800     2 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   13 __libc_csu_fini
    16: 0000000000400848     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   14 _fini
    17: 0000000000601034     4 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT   24 v_flag

Symbol table '.symtab' contains 65 entries:
                            ...
```

However, according to the man page

```
-rdynamic
    Pass the flag -export-dynamic to the ELF linker, on targets that support it. This instructs the linker to add all symbols, not only used ones, to the dynamic symbol table.
```

Hence, **question 2**, can we say that *v_flag* is **unused** (hence it does not appear in *dynsym*)? If so, why?

**Update 1:**

This issue does not show up in ld version 2.20.* (Thank Konstantin Vladimirov for pointing out this).

Answer (score 2):

First you should realize, that even with `rdynamic`, you are doing here something really awkward -- exporting position-dependent `v_flag` to dynamic loader specific `dynsym` section.

Answering your questions -- it is dropped because it is unused. **And** it is unused because it can not be used in any sensible dynamic context.

I think what you do really want -- is to compile a code to be positional independent:

```
gcc -o test test.c -fPIC
```

Now without any rdynamic hacks, you do have:

```
 0: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT  UND 
 1: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND printf@GLIBC_2.2.5 (2)
 2: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  WEAK   DEFAULT  UND __gmon_start__
 3: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND __libc_start_main@GLIBC_2.2.5 (2)
 4: 0000000000601020     4 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT   25 v_flag
```

I suggest you to read some docs on writing shared libraries. [This one is my favorite](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/m/a/1/e/dsohowto.pdf).

In assembly:

```
  .globl  v_flag
  .data
  .align 4
  .type v_flag, @object
  .size v_flag, 4
v_flag:
  .long 51914
```

Tested: GCC 4.4.3, GCC 4.7.2, GCC 4.8.2, GCC 4.9.2, linker ld 2.20.1

Comment: Thanks for very helpful answer. My terrible mistake that I forgot the -fPIC flag. However, even with *-fPIC*, the *v_flag* is still not in *dynsym*.  It's every weird to me since I am expecting *v_flag* in *dynsym*. I tested "-fPIC" with gcc 4.8.2 (not yet with gcc 4.4.7). What is the gcc version you tried?

Comment: I tested with gcc 4.4.7. *v_flag* does NOT appear in *dynsym*, even with "-fPIC".

Comment: It is really strange, because today I tested both 4.7.2, 4.8.2, 4.9.2 and 4.4.3 -- in all cases v_flag is in correct section (in case of fPIC compilation). My arch is x86_64, linker is 2.20.1

Comment: Great to hear from you. I tested with GNU ld version 2.20.51.0.2-20.fc13 20091009, and it worked. So, I guess the linker changed behaviors in later versions. The problem is that my current toolchain is using GNU ld version 2.23.52.0.1-16.el7 20130226. Really want to understand why there is such a change?

Answer (score 0):

Was not able to comment so had to write it here.

The same behavior(i.e doesn't show v_flag in dynsym table) happens in `GNU ld version 2.20.51.0.2-5.36.el6 20100205`.

So I guess edit out the Update in question as not all 2.20.* works.

So for now only way is to use -rdynamic, someone please add an answer if there is some other way, because -rdynamic feels like a hack.

Also I have seen cases where without rdynamic and also ld-version > 2.23 works, but I am not able to see the reason or reproduce it on why that works.